# how to Set TextSize correctly in android

Tags: android, xml

I am new in android and working on an application.  I have read a lot of articles, blogs  about how to set `Text Size` correctly in android, but unfortunately they didn't tell me something useful.

I use two different AVDs to test my application.
One of them is `Nexus One 480 * 800 hdpi` and another one is `Nexus 7 800*1280 tvdpi`.

I have created my UI in  `Nexus 7` . I have set `TextSize` to **72 Sp** & it shows very well! But when I changed the AVD it was not OK. The text was too big.
I thought if I use `sp` unit to define `textSize`, everything will go very well, but it didn't.
I have tried following things:

1. I used `sp` unit but it didn't work .
2. I tried to find a relation between density and `textSize` in one avd , and set that so that correct `textSize` is shown in any in any AVD , but it didn't work too.

   (During my experiments I found 213 density for Nexus 7. It was bigger than Nexus One.) I calculated density with this code:

   `int densityDpi = (int)(metrics.density*160);`
3. I read an article about this problem & it explained, you should create more than one UI for an application. According to this method, UI always shows correctly, but it didn't explain clearly how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is use res and override dimens.xml due to device used

Android gets the best resource base on the device used so you can use it do style layout, change language, theming and ofcourse, sizing.

```
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_body_1_material"
```

You need define abc_text_size_body_1_material in

```
res/values/dimens.xml
res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml
res/values-tvdpi/dimens.xml
```

More info http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: thank you .  how android realizes to use best dimens.xml ? and also we have ldpi , mdpi , hdpi and xhdpi .what does android do if my device belongs to xhdpi or ldpi ?? whould you explain me ?

Comment: In this case there is the base dimens.xml (res/values/dimens.xml) that will be used. For this reason, you must always define the base value of some resource (without it you will get an error while compile)